# How to import angularjs plugins manually in Eclipse?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create basic login page in AngularJS. I've tried to add Angulajs plugins via eclipse market place, but i couldn't do that.

Now i downloaded the plugins from site. How can i import the plugins to eclips?

Answer (score 0):

Use the files and Inject into the module.

```
app.module('modulename',['<inject the third party app/plugin>'])
```

include all the js-files needed in that plugin in ur html page. Use the controller and itsfunctions.